# If a six sided dice is marked with two A's, two B's, and two C's, what is the relative frequency of rolling an A if I throw the dice 20 times?

Tags: probability

I have come across this question regarding probability in a textbook while studying for an exam.

> If a six sided dice is marked with two A's, two B's, and two C's,
>
> What is the relative frequency of rolling an A if I throw the dice 20 times?

From what I understand of the question I think they're asking the probability of rolling an A *at least* once.
Either way, I don't think it's possible to calculate the relative frequency of a die before you have thrown the die since relative frequency is experimental. Even if we were to calculate the theoretical frequency, assuming that the question is written incorrectly and they mean theoretical frequency: $$\frac{2}{6}\times20=\frac{40}{6}=\frac{20}{3}$$It doesn't make sense that we would get a probability higher than $1$, as it's not guaranteed that we'd roll an A at all.

Comment: Relative frequency is the measure of how often a particular event occurs among total occurrences. The answer here is independent of the number of times you throw the dice since you would expect 'A' to occur $1/3$rd of the times the dice was thrown.

Comment: That's not exactly true, @Cathedral. You can't roll 0.66 of a die result!

Comment: @Nij While true, if you were to conduct the 20 rolls multiple times and then take the average of all those relative frequencies, you would approach $1/3$

Comment: But that would not be the relative frequency of the result in an experiment of 20 trials. You are conflating two concepts that are connected but distinct, and getting the wrong answer here.

Comment: If the question really is about the probability of getting $A$ at least once in $20$ throws, then the answer is $1-(2/3)^{20}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative frequency is the proportion of outcomes from a given experiment.

You're right that, without running that experiment, you can't give an answer to this question at all!

In theory, the expectation is that we roll $\frac{2}{6}\times 20=6.66$ 'A' results, so for discrete outcomes, we would most likely get 7, then 6 or 8 'A' results.

If this came to pass, the relative frequency of 'A' results in these experiments would be $\frac{7}{20}=0.35$ (respectively, $0.30$ or $0.40$).

Your calculation has left out division of the counted outcomes by the total number of trials required to get those outcomes - you would divide $\frac{20}{3}$ by $20$, getting $\frac{1}{3}$ as one would intuitively expect from two sides on a cubic die, if of course you somehow had indeed rolled $\frac{20}{3}$ 'A' results.